# How to get an array "complement" of another?

Tags: arrays, matlab, complement

the easiest way for me to explain what i want is with an example:

```
a = 1:20

b = [2,7,12,18]
```

Now I want `c` to be `[1,3,4,5,6,8,...,19,20]` with length `16`: `length(a) - length(b)` of course.

Is there a way for me to get `c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called *set difference* in most languages. In MATLAB, you can use the `setdiff` function:

```
a=1:20;
>> b=[2,7,12,18];
>> setdiff(a,b);

ans =

Columns 1 through 11

 1     3     4     5     6     8     9    10    11    13    14

Columns 12 through 16

15    16    17    19    20
```

Comment: function is useful for complicated cases, thx will take note for future use.

Comment: complement and set difference are synonymous. (at least applied to sets)

Comment: @Daniel: Indeed. Still it's useful to mention that most programming languages call it *difference*, to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 5):

You can delete array elements using `x(3)=[]`

```
c=a;
c(b)=[];
```

Comment: works for this simple case. But for the general case (where `b` contains elements to be removed from `a` instead of indices), use `setdiff`, as in the other answer.